# Status information from the batch process to be logged to a SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server

I plan to pass exam 'Querying Microsoft SQL Server 2012'. I would like to better understand one question.
Question is:

> You work as a database developer at ABC.com. ABC.com has a SQL Server
>   2012 database infrastructure with a very large database named SalesDB.
>   You create a new table named SalesHistory that will hold historical
>   data from the SalesDB database. You need to perform a batch update
>   from the SalesDB database to the SalesHistory table. You want the
>   status information from the batch process to be logged to a SQL Server
>   table that must be created by the batch process. How would you
>   accomplish this task?

Possible answer are:

> A. You should make use of the FORMAT function.
>
> B. You should make use of the CONVERT function.
>
> C. You should make use of a scalar user-defined function.
>
> D. You should make use of an inline function.
>
> E. You should make use of a table-valued function.
>
> F. You should make use of a stored procedure.

This is source : [How would you accomplish this task?](http://www.aiotestking.com/microsoft/how-would-you-accomplish-this-task-10/). I would test this, but I don't know how.
So tanks for help.

Comment: Since your stated goal is "I would like to better understand one question", can you clarify what it is you don't understand about this question?   Maybe share your thoughts on each of the answers, and why they might or might not be right?

Comment: My hint was F. Have one stored procedure that do all work. I don't see have can A or B could be correct, that not related to this task. I have just basic understanding of inline functions and table valued functions, and I never used them in real example. So I failed to see how is any of this connected to batch process. I am in process of learning so I need help.

Comment: I would agree that it's F.   But to explain the entire question and the virtues of each of the answers is too broad a topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Just tell me what is connection between batch process and stored procedure?

Comment: You can make executing the batch process one of the steps in the stored procedure.

Comment: A requirement is that the status of the batch must be logged to "a SQL Server table that must be created by the batch process" - functions cannot create tables but stored procedures can.